# Fill Chart dynamically with variables from Component

Tags: angular, typescript

i am new to Angular so i think i'm missing something.

i have 3 variables in my component, those variables are being filled after calling .subscribe method on an observable object.

like this

```
this.interRetard = this.technicienService.getInterRetard(id).subscribe(data => {
  this.interRetard = data;
});
```

the interRetard variable contains a number, i can display its value in the html by doing {{interRetard}} .

the problem is that when i try to display it with console.log() it says :

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
```

and i need it to give me the exact value like it is displaying it in the html so i can assign it to the chart like this

```
public doughnutChartData:number[] = [this.interRetard ,  5, 10];
```

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be using `this.interRetard` 2 times. Once to hold the subscription returned by the subscribe, and again when you assign `data` to it *inside* the subscribe.

Comment: `this.interRetard` is being assigned twice in your statement. You only need to assign it inside the `subscribe` callback.

Comment: i removed it and something weird is happepning :/ when i do console.log(interRetard) it displayes undefined then when i trigger the method again (selection changed of a select box) it shows the right value :/ :/

Comment: What is the type of your `interRetard` ?

Comment: the type is any .. i have bad news also this is not working  doughnutChartData:number[] = [this.interRetard ,this.interFinie,this.interAvance];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
   this.technicienService.getInterRetard(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.interRetard = data;
      console.log(this.iterRetard);
      this.myFunction(this.iterRetard) or this.myFunction(data);
    });

myFunction(p) {
// Your Logic //
}
```

Comment: yes i know this works .. but i need the variable outside the method subscribe so i can put it in an array and assign the array to a chart like this ... public doughnutChartData:number[] = [this.interRetard ,this.interFinie,this.interAvance];

Comment: can you please explain your last comment .. i don't seem to get what u're saying

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: @kmarakrout: that comment was partial, so removed it!

Comment: no problem .. i think your answer is working .. i'm trying something if it works perfectly i'll let you know .. thanks